# Fourier series convergence of continuous function

Tags: convergence-divergence, continuity, fourier-series

What can one tell about Fourier series convergence for a real continuous function (without any other assumptions)?

Is it true that the Fourier series will always pointwise converge to f almost everywhere? Is there a short answer to the question why can't we expect any stronger convergence (uniformly convergence or pointwise convergence everywhere)?

How about real continuous $2 \pi $-periodic functions?

Comment: No. For Fejer's well known counter-example see p. 154 of Fourier Series by R E Edwards.

Comment: Or see this: https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/continuous-function-with-divergent-fourier-series/

Comment: If I got this right, the Fourier series of this function diverges at 0. Since this is only one point, it could still be convergent almost everywhere. Or not?

Comment: Search the web for Carleson's Theorem . Almost everywhere convergence is true, but this is a VERY DEEP theorem.